# Excel - ifBLANK / Auto Hide empty rows

Tags: excel, hide, rows

I want to copy a cell to another sheet. I am using ifblank statement. The problem I am having with new sheet, it shows a lot of empty rows. How can I copy a cell if there is value other than that it should skip copy blank to the new sheet.Or in another way, how can I auto hide all empty rows?

Please and Thank you!

Salah

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to sort your data it will push all the blanks to the end.  | Data tab > Sort | You may also just filter the data and hide blanks from the drop down selection. | Data tab > Filter |

Comment: @Salah I agree with Michal; filtering the data first, and then copying, is likely the simplest solution. Note that this requires the data being copied to be Values, and not formulas. Formulas will not copy over properly (will be replaced with values) if you copy filtered data.

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to VBA, try this:

```
Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

That will delete all the blank rows that you have between your data.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try a formula like this (e.g. if your data are in A1:A10):-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$10,SMALL(IF(A$1:A$10<>"",ROW(A$1:A$10)),ROW())),"")
```

Put it in B1 and pull down. It must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Or

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(A:A<>"",ROW(A:A)),ROW())),"")
```

for the entire column.

Comment: I have some data in one sheet. say row 1 - 100 and some row has no value. Now in new sheet I am trying to copy the rows which has value only. I am using this - =IF('Marketing Requests'!V22 = ISBLANK(FALSE)," ",'Marketing Requests'!X22). But problem it pulls all blank rows and people needs to manually filter to see data only. How can I do it automatically. Thanks!

Comment: I think we would need some examples of the data to give more specific help, I know that's difficult with limited rep.

Comment: I can't show example with image. Here is what I am doing, In sheet 1 say I have 3 col (Name, ID, Date) Now In 2nd sheet I want to match Name (If x then copy to sheet 2 ID & Date) I use this formula =IF(FIND("Yes",Sheet1!A2)<>0,Sheet1!B2,""). it copies fine but it keeps blank rows where i do not have data.

Comment: It only makes sense if you have another column containing yes/no, e.g. (YesNo, Name, ID Date) and maybe you only want to copy the rows that say "Yes"?

Comment: Or perhaps you already have a list of names in the second sheet that you want to match with the first sheet? If so, are they in the same order?

Comment: Hi Tom I appreciate your help. Here is what I tried but it shows wrong address. =IFERROR(INDEX('Marketing Requests'!U22:U84,SMALL(IF('Marketing Requests'!U22:U84<>"",ROW('Marketing Requests'!U22:U84)),ROW())),"")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85417/discussion-between-salah-and-tom-sharpe).

Comment: Hi I just resolved the issue. I applied iferror array. Only thing is, it's not showing 0. say if I have 0 in the cell it shows blank.

Comment: Not sure about that last one (not showing zero), would need a link to some sample data.

Comment: say In sheet 1 cell I have 0 and on sheet 2  I want to see the "0" even as anumeric value. but when I run the array formula I do not see 0.